# Return Yield for interface generic classes

Tags: c#, csv

I am struggling with how to return Yield for type that is interface type of IBasic. Currently i can have three diffrent types of IBasic: InputData1, InputData2, InputData3.

The problem is on this part of code:

```
 internal class CsvRepo<T> : ICsvRepo<T> where T : IBasic
    {
        private readonly ICsvSettings _settings;
        public CsvRepo(ICsvSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetRecords()
        {
            //return from line in File.ReadLines(_settings.Path)
            //    select line.Split(',') into parts
            //    where parts.Length == 3
            //    select new InputData { X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };
        }
    }
```

in the line: `select new InputData`

i am going to say something like `return new IBasic` but diffrent InputDataX has diffrent parameters and i am not sure how to do so? Is it possible?

**This is full code:**

```
namespace ClassLibrary3
{
    public interface IRepo { }
    public interface IRepository<T> : IRepo where T : IBasic { }

    public interface ICsvRepo<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IBasic
    {
        IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
    }

    public interface ISqlRepo
    {
    }

    public interface IOracleRepo<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IBasic { }

    public interface IRepoX : IRepo { }

    public interface ICsvSettings
    {
        string Path { get; }
        string FileName { get; }
    }

    public interface ISqlSettings
    {
        string ConnectionString { get; }
        string Username { get; }
        string Password { get; }
    }

    internal class CsvSettings : ICsvSettings
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
    }

    internal class SqlSettings : ISqlSettings
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }


    internal class CsvRepo<T> : ICsvRepo<T> where T : IBasic
    {
        private readonly ICsvSettings _settings;
        public CsvRepo(ICsvSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> GetRecords()
        {
            return null;
            //return from line in File.ReadLines(_settings.Path)
            //    select line.Split(',') into parts
            //    where parts.Length == 3
            //    select new InputData { X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };
        }
    }

    internal class SqlRepo : ISqlRepo
    {
        private readonly ISqlSettings _settings;
        private readonly IRepoX _repoX;

        public SqlRepo(ISqlSettings settings, IRepoX repoX)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _repoX = repoX;
        }
    }

    internal class OracleRepo<T> : IOracleRepo<T> where T : IBasic
    {
        private readonly ISqlSettings _settings;
        private readonly IRepoX _repoX;

        public OracleRepo(ISqlSettings settings, IRepoX repoX)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _repoX = repoX;
        }
    }

    internal class OracleRepo333<T> : IOracleRepo<T> where T : IBasic
    {
        private readonly ISqlSettings _settings;
        private readonly IRepoX _repoX;

        public int id;

        public OracleRepo333(ISqlSettings settings, IRepoX repoX)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _repoX = repoX;
        }
    }

    internal class RepoX : IRepoX { }

    public class RepoModule : NinjectModule
    {
        private readonly string _username;
        private readonly string _password;
        public RepoModule(string username, string password)
        {
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
        }
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<ICsvSettings>().ToConstant(new CsvSettings
            {
                FileName = "foo",
                Path = Config.Instance.ServerName,
            }).InSingletonScope();

            Bind<ISqlSettings>().ToConstant(new SqlSettings
            {
                ConnectionString = "foo",
                Password = _password,
                Username = _username
            }).InSingletonScope();



            Bind<IRepoX>().To<RepoX>();

            Bind(typeof(ICsvRepo<>)).To(typeof(CsvRepo<>));
            Bind(typeof(ISqlRepo)).To(typeof(SqlRepo));

            Bind(typeof(IOracleRepo<>)).To(typeof(OracleRepo<>));
            Bind(typeof(IOracleRepo<>)).To(typeof(OracleRepo333<>));
        }
    }

    public interface IBasic
    {
    }

    public class InputData1 : IBasic
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }

    public class InputData2 : IBasic
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    public class InputData3 : IBasic
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> WhateverList;
    }

}

  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel(new RepoModule("foo", "bar")); /*some other modules here maybe?*/

            //thousand of code lines later...

            var csvRepo = kernel.Get<ICsvRepo<InputData1>>();
            //var data = FetchData(csvRepo);

            var sqlRepo = kernel.Get<ISqlRepo>();
            //data = FetchData(sqlRepo);

           // var oracleRepo = kernel.Get<IOracleRepo<InputData>>();
            //data = FetchData(oracleRepo);

            var oracleRepos = kernel.GetAll<List<IOracleRepo<InputData1>>>();}
            }

        }

        //static T[] FetchData<T>(IRepository<InputData> repo)
        //{
        //    throw new NotImplementedException();
        //}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to return a concrete type where a generic type is expected. Consider the following instantiation of `CsvRepo<T>`

```
var repo = new CsvRepo<InputData1Derived>(null);
repo.GetRecords().First().PropFromInputData1Derived
```

You are instantiating `InputData` while the caller expects `InputDataDerived`. This is why the compiler does not let you do this.

You could have several solutions, let `CsvRepo` could be abstract and implement it for specific classes:

```
internal abstract class CsvRepo<T> : ICsvRepo<T> where T : IBasic
{
    public CsvRepo()
    {
    }

    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetRecords();
}

internal class InputDataCsvRepo : CsvRepo<InputData1>
{
    public override IEnumerable<InputData1> GetRecords()
    {
        return from line in File.ReadLines(_settings.Path)
               select line.Split(',') into parts
               where parts.Length == 3
               select new InputData { X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };

    }
}
```

Or you can make the `T` parameter have a default constructor and use that (but only properties in `IBasic` will be initializable which is not what you want probably.

Comment: i was thinking about this, in this case CsvRepo would be just starting point to create more concrete repos like your's InputDataCsvRepo, this make sense to me it could be then: InputDataCsvRepo , InputData2CsvReport etc. This case we going out issue i had. I just thought this could be done within one repo but not.

Comment: @stackoverflow you can do it with one repo class, if the class accepts a `Func<IEnumerble<T>>` which is the actual creator for the result of `GetRecords`. You'd be getting around the need for more classes using a bit of functional programming. If you want I  can expand on this in the answer

Comment: Hi there Titian, I think your asnwer is just enough because concrete repos could be created based on very generic one containing specific type and this is also probably the way it should be. At the end there should be some concrete repo/s to be used which is exactly what you've shown. Thx

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of those situations where [if you have a hammer everything looks like a nail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument#Computer_programming). In short there is no need to make the argument for the method generic as already know the concrete return type for any implementation and you want that return type to implement a specific interface.

Remove the generic type constraint `T` on method `GetRecords` and replace it with `IBasic` interface constraint.

```
public interface ICsvRepo<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IBasic
{
    IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords();
}

internal class CsvRepo<T> : ICsvRepo<T> where T : IBasic
{
    private readonly ICsvSettings _settings;
    public CsvRepo(ICsvSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }

    public IEnumerable<IBasic> GetRecords()
    {
        return from line in File.ReadLines(_settings.Path)
            select line.Split(',') into parts
            where parts.Length == 3
            select new InputData { X = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Y = Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]) };
    }
}
```

*I altered your code below to only include what is needed to show the solution.*

---

On an unrelated note making fields public is almost always a bad idea because you expose the internals of the class. Make them into properties instead with public getter/setters.

Example:

```
public class InputData : IBasic
{
    public int X {get;set;}
    public int Y {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Do not agree. In this case there is still specific type: InputData  returned which makes IBasic completly no sense to have, that's because every time InpoutData will be returned even if i want to use InputData2. No sense then for IBasic. I was at that point before also. If you look at Titian's post makes more sense to me to create 'real' sub-repos. For time being i do not see other solutions.